# PGFPLOTs bar chart with zero data ymin=0 not respected

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have simple bar chart. With zero values in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
axis lines*=left,
ymajorgrids,
bar width=0.26cm, width=0.45\textwidth,
ymin=0,
y tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
ylabel= Number ,
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
x tick label style={font=\footnotesize,align=right,rotate=90},
every tick/.style={color=black, line width=0.35pt},
xticklabels from table={\datatable}{month},
enlarge x limits=0.1,
]
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=2] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My data file is :

```
 month  aa  bb  c
 June   0   0   0
 July   0   0   0
 August 7   0   7
 September  6   0   6
 October    4   0   4
 November   5   0   5
 December   5   0   5
 January    4   0   4
 February   0   0   0
 March  0   0   0
 April  0   0   0
 May    0   0   0
 June   0   0   0
```

As you can column with index=2 values are 0. And the result chart is

[image]

In my chart styles I have ymin=0. But it does not work as you can see.

Any solution for this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you take a look at the `.log` file, you'll see the following message: `Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is [0.0:0.0])`. You can fix this issue by either using proper data (which isn't all zeros), or explicitly setting the upper limit using `ymax=1`, for instance.

Comment: @RusAlex, did the tip of Jake help you to solve the problem or do you need further assistance. In the first case I would close the question as being solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Jake's comment solves the problem.